Does tetration go up or down? (and other related questions)
Tetration is defined as “repeated exponentiation” - that is, $2$ tetrated to $5$ is equal to $2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}$, just as $2$ exponentiated to $5$ is equal to $2\cdot{2}\cdot{2}\cdot{2}\cdot{2}$ (repeated multiplication). My first basic question is:

Does tetration go “up” or “down”?

That is, stated more clearly, do you resolve the exponentiations on the bottom or the top first? For example, you can solve $2$ tetrated to $5$ as
$$2^{2^{2^{2^2}}} = 4^{2^{2^2}} = 16^{2^2} =256^2=65536 = 2^{16}$$
or
$$2^{2^{2^{2^2}}} = 2^{2^{2^4}} = 2^{2^{16}}= 2^{65536}.$$
The simple fact that we get two different results depending on the order in which we perform the exponentiation makes tetration unique. Addition and multiplication are both commutative (e.g. $2 \cdot (3 \cdot 4) = (2 \cdot 3) \cdot 4$ but exponentiation is not (e.g. $(3^3)^3 \neq 3^{(3^3)}$). This is why we get this ambiguity about tetration that is absent for addition, multiplication, and exponentiation. Another question:

Is this ambiguity present for the further hyperoperations? If so, do they go “up” or “down” as well?

In addition, there is a multiplication identity for exponentiation:
$$(x^m)^n = x^{mn}$$

Is there an analogue to this for tetration or the other hyperoperators?

Finally:

Is there a standard notation for all the hyperoperators? What about hyperoperator roots (just as $\sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x} = x$, a “tetrational square root” defined as $k =$ [$x$ tetrated to $\tfrac{1}{2}$] where $k^k = x$)?

Thanks for your assistance!

$a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$, not $(a^b)^c$.

See Knuth's up-arrow notation.

As you know that $(a^{b})^c=a^{bc}$, doing tetration from the bottom up would be quite boring. $n$ tetrated to  $k$ could be simplified to $n^{(n^{k-1})}$.

Duplicate of  Notation: parsing convention for iterated exponentiaks like ${{2^2}^2}^3$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also many other dupes e.g. What is the order when doing $x^{y^z}$  and why? $\ \ $

Tetration is evaluated from the top of the exponent going downwards as mentioned in the Wiki page. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)
So, it'd be $2^{65536}$ for your first question.
Usually, definitions of such `hyperoperators' are given recursively to avoid ambiguity. For example, let $t(a,n)$ denote $a$ tetrated to $n$.
It is defined recursively as $t(a,n) = a^{t(a,n-1)}$ if $n > 0$, and $1$ otherwise.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.ov
